# Clarification on maxResults and nextPageToken using Google Drive API v2

Tags: google-drive-api

I just wanted clarification with regard to the Files: list feature of the Google Drive API here:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

What is the the maximum value that can be specified with maxResults? I assume this value calculates the number of results on the next page of results?

Also, is the nextPageToken simply part of the query string that's required to be passed with nextLink to get the next page of results?

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `maxResults` query parameter can be used to limit (or increase) the number of items returned in a list request. There is a default value and a hard limit that is set by our server.
Unfortunately, we don't usually document those numbers as they can easily change and recommend developers to look for a `nextPageToken` and/or `nextLink` in the resulting collection to know whether or not all items have been returned.

The `nextPageToken` attribute is to be used as the `pageToken` query parameter on a list request. If you are using the `nextLink` from the resulting collection, you do not need to specify the `pageToken` query parameter as it should already be included.

Comment: So if there are 100 files in the Drive and I set maxResults to 10, will I still be able to list all files, in 10 consecutive requests?

Comment: can you tell us a ballpark for the hard limit on maxResults? is it above 500 or so at least?

Comment: Great comment. Do we know if any `pageToken`'s are bypassed when using `nextLink`?

Comment: how can I get the records more than 1000 - pls refer my question in this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572228/how-to-list-of-more-than-1000-records-from-google-drive-api-v3-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

maxResults cannot be larger than 1000 according to this page: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: The actual upper value is 460 - and it is falsely documented as 1000.

Comment: @DAdams yes, I was wondering why I got always 460 files even when setting 1000

Comment: The real upper limit still seems to be 460 now (October 2021), though the error response says the maximum value is 1000 if pageSize is set to > 1000